# What is meant by four-state address input?

Tags: i2c, datasheet

Regarding [this](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/dac60501.pdf?ts=1682284291531) DAC (TI DACx0501) and assuming it is operated via I2C A0 pin, what is meant by "Four-state address input 0."?

[image: Four-state address input 0.]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The A0 pin can be connected to one of four signals as described in section 8.5.1.2.2.1 *DACx0501 Address Byte* on page 28:

> The address byte, as shown in Table 2, is the first byte received
> following the START condition from the master device. The first four
> bits (MSBs) of the address are factory preset to 1001. The next three
> bits of the address are controlled by the A0 pin. **The A0 pin input can
> be connected to VDD, AGND, SCL, or SDA.** The A0 pin is sampled during
> the first byte of each data frame to determine the address. The device
> latches the value of the address pin, and consequently, responds to
> that particular address according to Table 3.

The A0 pin is used to select the slave address for the device.  The device supports 4 different 7-bit slave addresses as given in Table 3: 0x48, 0x49, 0x4a, 0x4b.  It would be more straightforward to use 2 pins to select one of the four addresses, but on a low pin-count device like this, it can be achieved with a single pin.

The internal implementation details of how the signals are sensed are irrelevant on a datasheet.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What confuses me though SDA and SCL pins are alternating between 0 and 1. How come they lead a constant address? How come this DAC would sense whether pin A0 is connected to SDA or SCL?

Comment: @cm64: You're welcome.  The intent is to allow one of these DAC devices to have one of 4 slave addresses.  Using just a single extra pin (A0), the device is able to determine which of the 4 to use.  The selection would be more straightforward with 2 extra pins, but this method saves one pin.

Comment: @cm64  The chip does not just use the logic level of the A0 pin to decide what signal it is connected to - then it would always sense either Vcc or GND. From page 28: * The A0 pin input can be connected to VDD, AGND, SCL, or SDA. The A0 pin is
sampled during the first byte of each data frame to determine the address.* When I2C communication begins, the chip watches the A0 pin for the first couple of transitions - START condition and the first SCL rising edge probably - and compares it to GND, SDA, SCL, and Vcc using sampling. Whichever signal it mirrors is the one that it is connected to.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60272538/how-can-we-use-sda-or-scl-lines-for-i2c-addresses The answer to this question explains it in more detail.

Comment: What happens when A0 is floating. Like in such case here?: https://download.mikroe.com/documents/add-on-boards/click/dac_8_click/DAC-8-click-schematic-v101.pdf

Comment: @cm64: Since the datasheet does not specify the case of a floating A0 input, you should  make 1 of the 4 legal connections.

Comment: interesting these guys are selling this sensor I thought they were very professional.  https://www.mikroe.com/dac-8-click seems they didnt care about A0